# Removing small black contours/unwanted contours in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, opencv

I have been at this all day, how to we remove the small back noise in the red circle? I would need it to work on other samples of pictures like this.

The idea I used is to findContours and then add a mask with all the small black noise that is less than a certain area (trial and error).

[Removing noise in red ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o4XU.png)

```
image = cv2.imread("11_Image_after_noise_removal.png")

# copy image
img = image.copy()
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = 255 - thresh
# Use cv2.CCOMP for two level hierarchy
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Use cv2.CCOMP for two level hierarchy
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("First detection", img)
# loop through the contours
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    # if the contour has no other contours inside of it
    if hierarchy[0][i][3] != -1:  # basically look for holes
        # if the size of the contour is less than a threshold (noise)
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 70:
            # Fill the holes in the original image
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 0), -1)
            # display result
# Visualize the image after the Otsu's method application

cv2.imshow("Image after noise removal", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows().destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try blurring the image

Comment: Either filter the contours on area or use morphology close to remove the small stuff

Answer (score 1):

You might check the contour area using `area = cv.contourArea(cnt)` and if it is below some threshold, ignore it.

Here is the OpenCV documentations:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html